# SPFx Extension doesn't reload after site search

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have an application customizer extension loading content into the Top Place Holder.

- When performing a "More Results" site search the page slides over to a search detail screen.
- When I exit the search detail screen the page slides back and partially reloads without re-rendering or initializing the extension or it's content.

How are we able to reload an extension when these partial page load events occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the latest update regarding this bug: [SPFx Application Customizer](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1042)